# Deserialization abstract class implementation .Net Core C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, .net-core, abstract-class

Short explanation:
Project in Angular and .NetCore where I try to update a list of abstract classes in my backend. 
By creating a put request I update the container model which holds the list I want to update.
The frontend serialises the container model with `JSON.stringify();`

When my put request reaches my endpoint it starts deserializing right away. And I get the exception:
System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor is not supported. Type 'Tile'.

This exception does not surprise me because the abstract class can not be instantiated. So I tried using a custom JsonConverter which defines when to convert to which class. But this Converter never gets called. I have a breakpoint placed in the ReadJson method but the exception is thrown before it reaches the breakpoint.

[Custom JsonConverter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00cxF.png)

[Abstract model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGzJS.png)

[Implementation of the abstract class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz7Wy.png)

[Put Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJsdE.png)

### Update:

So after continuing for a couple of hours I found out that my project uses System.Text.Json.Serialization for serializing the object. The CostumConverter I created is a Newtonsoft. That's why it probably isn't called.
Is there a way to specify to my project which to use?
I have a startup.cs File where I think stuff like this might go.

Comment: is the `CanConvert` on the converter method being invoked?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It is not being invoked.

Comment: There are two options then: One, Apply the converter whereever your actual property is; Two, Add the converter to your deserialization config. (either the default one or on every deserialization individually)

Answer (score 0):

you can use generic type parameter, allows you to specify an arbitrary type T to a method at compile time, without specifying a concrete type in the method or class declaration.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters